# CompletableFuture chain not calling thenAcceptAsync

Tags: java, completable-future

`doTask()` is a method that performs something if `previousStepResult` is successful, otherwise logs and return `previousStepResult` as is. Below code works fine and `conclude()` is also executed but only when there no exceptions (errors). But if there are exceptions (which are well handled) the code returns false. So in case of error, the next step is called fine and as said, logs and return false. However `conclude` is not called at all. I am not sure if there is an impact of exceptions inside each step preventing `thenAcceptAsync` to be executed or what. Any clues ?

```
return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> doTask("task1", true), taskExecutor).
                thenApplyAsync(previousStepResult -> doTask("task2", previousStepResult),taskExecutor).
                thenApplyAsync(previousStepResult -> doTask("task3", previousStepResult),taskExecutor).
                thenAcceptAsync(previousStepResult -> conclude(previousStepResult),taskExecutor);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CompletableFuture::handle` or `CompletableFuture::handleAsync` after the step that is likely to throw error. This would result in further steps being called as it is, else would be skipped.